# What the equivalent of "this" (as in Java or C++) in S4 object system in R

Tags: r, r-s4

Now I understand that the S4 object system of R is very different from C++ or Java.

However I had the question is there anything similar to the "this" in S4

Comment: R doesn't do pass-by-reference (at least, not in S4) so the idea of any kind of pointer (specifically the this pointer) doesn't really translate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods are defined on generics and dispatch on class, rather than on classes. So `this` is always the object being dispatched on.

```
.A = setClass("A", slots = c(a = "integer"))

setGeneric("foo", function(x) standardGeneric("foo"))

setMethod("foo", "A", function(x) {
   x@a        # 'x' is the object that `foo()` dispatches on, i.e., 'this'
})
```

Usage:

```
> y = .A(a=1:5)
> foo(y)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```